# How do i compile .jar with jre?

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I have a friend without java. I want to package my executable .jar file with java platform SE binary in an exe file so he can run it without downloading the entire java runtime. Could someone point out some kind of software that does that?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a friend without java.

And you call them a friend? ;)

- Use [`deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to check the user has the minimum Java required to run the app.
- Install & launch the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).
- Give the user a link to the 'launch' web page.

This will work on Windows ..and OS X ..& *nix.

Comment: So webstart would embed it to a webpage?

Comment: Not if it is a frame based app.  Even applets can be launched free-floating using JWS (but in later JREs, can also remain embedded).

Comment: So What does The webstart do?

Comment: If the info. page on JWS (which I wrote, BTW) with all its information & further links failed to explain it to you, then my attempts here wold be pointless (not that I am about to try).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Launch4J at http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Here's the highlights:

> Launch4j wraps jars in Windows native executables and allows to run them like a regular Windows program. It's possible to wrap applications on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and Solaris!
>
> Also creates launchers for jars and class files without wrapping.

Comment: I can't figure out how to package the jre with the exe... What do I do?

Comment: Question not understood, that does not give the result

Answer (score 0):

I have also had good experiences with Launch4j. Also check out JSmooth: (http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/index.php) which claims to have an option to download and install a JVM if one is not available.